# sticky selected cell in UITableView like the new twitter ipad app?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

any idea how to have the selected cell in UITableView sticky and remain visible while scrolling? like how the twitter ipad app works. i would like it on my splitview's uitableview.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a UITableViewController right? This automatically deselects a selected row. To avoid this, the best option would be to use a normal UIViewController with the protocols UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Building from a comment Vince made on my previous answer (since deleted since it was more of an explanation of how long and how much effort a feature like this would take rather than an attempt at answering the question).

You could store the index path of a cell when it becomes selected, and then as the cell is about to scroll offscreen (you'll need some trickery to detect this) you could retrieve the cell view returned from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and set a section header view to use this cell view.

This would be a pretty monstrous hack though, and you'd need to find a way to elegantly split the table into sections in order to use the section header.

I wouldn't recommend this approach, although its a step in the right direction.

Comment: yes it will be an ugly hack. i hope someone can have a better solution.